# How to save tinymce using asp button

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I'm using asp.net and c# to build a website that can upload,edit,save the file. I have use tinymce as the texteditor but the problem is the I dint know how to configure the save plugins in tinymce..I have add asp button to use as save button but how to configure it to save into file .html?

javascript to replace tiny with texeditor:

```
           $('#<%=btnsave.ClientID%>').show()  //save button
           tinymce.init({selector: "textarea"});   //replace texteditor
```

this is markup code:

```
            <textarea name="textarea" cols="100" rows="5" style="visibility: hidden;">
            </textarea>
            <br /><asp:Button Text="Save" runat="server" ID="btnsave" style="display:none;" onclick="btnsave_Click" />
```

This in code behind

```
           protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
              {
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/WordExcelPPointToHtml/test.html");
                File.WriteAllText(path,HtmlTextArea);     //this line have error!!
              }
```

Can anyone help me on this ?. Thanks in advance. Eagerly waiting for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the html control with an ASP.NET web control, and they you will be able to access the value programmatically in the code behind.

E.g.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" Name="textarea" Columns="100" Rows="5" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="Server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And in the code behind:

```
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/WordExcelPPointToHtml/test.html");
    File.WriteAllText(path, txt.Text);
}
```

You should also consider some error handling in `btnSave_Click`